# Multiplying RGBA with two CGImageRefs

Tags: core-graphics, cgcontext, cgimage, masking

I'd like to multiply r, g, b and a values of two CGImages, to use a single image as both a mask (in its alpha channel) and tint (in the rgb channels). I first tried simply:

```
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, _w, _h), handle());
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, other->width(), other->height()), over);
```

However, this only tints, and does not mask. Thus, I extracted the alpha from the masking image into a CGImage mask grayscale image (using a CGDataProvider) and used that as a mask on the context:

```
// "mask" is "other"'s alpha channel as an inverted grayscale image
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextClipToMask(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, other->width(), other->height()), mask);
CGImageRelease(mask);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, _w, _h), handle());
CGContextRestoreGState(context); // Don't apply the clip mask to 'other', since it already has it
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, other->width(), other->height()), other->handle());
```

It still won't look right, though. The image gets *lighter*; should a multiplied image be always at least darker? Previews of images at:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6775/multiply/index.html

Thanks in advance for enlightenment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is that you don't need to extract the alpha channel to a separate channel to do masking. You can just draw it with `kCGBlendModeDestinationIn`. For an inverted mask, same thing, but with `kCGBlendModeDestinationOut`.

So, the solution is to draw the second image with Multiply, then draw it again with Destination In or Out.

Comment: That is an *excellent* solution, but I just realized why I never considered it: this app must support 10.4 :( (I'll mark it as correct though, as it *is* correct for the stated question)